# Why wont this loop? Getting - TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Tags: javascript

I am still learning JavaScript, so any use full advice is always welcome.
I am making a lottery simulator, Its all working well but.....
When I click the function to run, the random numbers are generated and comparisons made, however when I try to loop the function I get - TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null.

I have tried a few things but think I am totally scratching my head with this.

The code in question is.

```
 var automateLottery = function(){
    numberOfWeeks = numberOfWeeks + 1;//tally up rounds
    //drawUniqueNumbers();

var p_01 = parseInt(document.getElementById("picked_number_01").value);
var p_02 = parseInt(document.getElementById("picked_number_02").value);
var p_03 = parseInt(document.getElementById("picked_number_03").value);
var p_04 = parseInt(document.getElementById("picked_number_04").value);
var p_05 = parseInt(document.getElementById("picked_number_05").value);
var p_06 = parseInt(document.getElementById("picked_number_06").value);

var r_01 = parseInt(document.getElementById("random_01").value);
var r_02 = parseInt(document.getElementById("random_02").value);
var r_03 = parseInt(document.getElementById("random_03").value);
var r_04 = parseInt(document.getElementById("random_04").value);
var r_05 = parseInt(document.getElementById("random_05").value);
var r_06 = parseInt(document.getElementById("random_06").value);


if(p_01===r_01||p_01===r_02||p_01===r_03||p_01===r_04||p_01===r_05||p_01=== r_06){
        document.getElementById("compare_01").value = ("You have matched number " + " " +p_01 );
        addUpMatches(1);
    }else{
        document.getElementById("compare_01").value = ("No matches" )
    };

if(p_02===r_01||p_02===r_02||p_02===r_03||p_02===r_04||p_02===r_05||p_02===r_06){
        document.getElementById("compare_02").value = ("You have matched number" + " " +p_02 );
        addUpMatches(1);
    }else{
        document.getElementById("compare_02").value = ("No matches" )
    };      

if(p_03===r_01||p_03===r_02||p_03===r_03||p_03===r_04||p_03===r_05||p_03===r_06){
        document.getElementById("compare_03").value = ("You have matched number" + " " +p_03 );
        addUpMatches(1);
    }else{
        document.getElementById("compare_03").value = ("No matches" )
    };

if(p_04===r_01||p_04===r_02||p_04===r_03||p_04===r_04||p_04===r_05||p_04===r_06){
        document.getElementById("compare_04").value = ("You have matched number" + " " +p_04 );
        addUpMatches(1);
    }else{
        document.getElementById("compare_04").value = ("No matches" )
    };

if(p_05===r_01||p_05===r_02||p_05===r_03||p_05===r_04||p_05===r_05||p_05===r_06){
        document.getElementById("compare_05").value = ("You have matched number" + " " +p_05);
        addUpMatches(1);
    }else{
        document.getElementById("compare_05").value = ("No matches" )
    };

if(p_06===r_01||p_06===r_02||p_06===r_03||p_06===r_04||p_06===r_05||p_06===r_06){
        document.getElementById("compare_06").value = ("You have matched number" + " " +p_06 );
        addUpMatches(1);
    }else{
        document.getElementById("compare_06").value = ("No matches" )
    };



declareMatches();//----Add up per round and total
    document.getElementById("amountOfMatched").value = ("You have matched" + " " +totalMatchedThisRound + " "+ "numbers"); 
    document.getElementById("weeks").value = ("You have played for" + " " +numberOfWeeks + " "+ "and have won £"+ totalWinnings );
    document.getElementById("amountOfThreeMatches").value = ("You have so far had" + " " +match3 + " "+ "matches of three"  );
    document.getElementById("amountOffourMatches").value = ("You have so far had" + " " +match4 + " "+ "matches of four"  );
    document.getElementById("amountOffiveMatches").value = ("You have so far had" + " " +match5 + " "+ "matches of five"  );
    document.getElementById("amountOfsixMatches").value = ("You have so far had" + " " +match6 + " "+ "matches of six"  );

    clearCount();//clears amount matched every round
    cleartempTotal();//clears total matched every round

 };

 for( var i = 0; i < 10 ; i++){
    automateLottery();
 };
```

HTML:

```
<div id="random_numbers">
<FORM NAME="random_numbs" ACTION="" METHOD="GET">

    <INPUT TYPE="text" class="ran_numb" id="random_01" NAME="slot_01" VALUE="">
    <INPUT TYPE="text" class="ran_numb" id="random_02" NAME="slot_02" VALUE="">
    <INPUT TYPE="text" class="ran_numb" id="random_03" NAME="slot_03" VALUE="">
    <INPUT TYPE="text" class="ran_numb" id="random_04" NAME="slot_04" VALUE="">
    <INPUT TYPE="text" class="ran_numb" id="random_05" NAME="slot_05" VALUE="">
    <INPUT TYPE="text" class="ran_numb" id="random_06" NAME="slot_06" VALUE="">
    <br/><br/>
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button2" Value="Draw Numbers"      onClick="drawUniqueNumbers()">
</FORM>
```

```
 <div id="matched_numbers">
<FORM NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="GET">

    <INPUT TYPE="text"  NAME="matched_01" id="compare_01" VALUE=""><br>
    <INPUT TYPE="text"  NAME="matched_02" id="compare_02" VALUE=""><br>
    <INPUT TYPE="text"  NAME="matched_03" id="compare_03" VALUE=""><br>
    <INPUT TYPE="text"  NAME="matched_04" id="compare_04" VALUE=""><br>
    <INPUT TYPE="text"  NAME="matched_05" id="compare_05" VALUE=""><br>
    <INPUT TYPE="text"  NAME="matched_06" id="compare_06" VALUE=""><br>
    <br/>
    <INPUT TYPE="text"  NAME="numbers3" id="amountOfMatched" VALUE="You have matched 0 numbers"><br>
    <br>

    <INPUT TYPE="text"  NAME="numbers4" id="amountOfThreeMatches" VALUE=""><br>
    <INPUT TYPE="text"  NAME="numbers5" id="amountOffourMatches" VALUE=""><br>
    <INPUT TYPE="text"  NAME="numbers6" id="amountOffiveMatches" VALUE=""><br>
    <INPUT TYPE="text"  NAME="numbers6" id="amountOfsixMatches" VALUE=""><br>
    Stats<br>
    <INPUT TYPE="text"  NAME="weeks"  id="weeks" VALUE=""><br>
</FORM>
```

This is some of the html.

Just to confirm there are values going into the forms and variables.
I set up a button to trigger the function "automateLottery" which works fine.
It takes random numbers generated and compares them with numbers picked, then compiles the stats.
Trouble is when I set up automateLottery in a loop, it will not work.

Should I put up all my code here? Or is this enough?

Thanks again

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: Does an element with that `id` exist?

Comment: Please add the HTML that goes with this. The reason you are getting null data is because you are trying to reference an HTML node that doesn't contain anything.

Comment: Just to mention: You should never write code that repeats in this way. There is always a better solution. In this example you should save `p` values in an array and then check if your p array contains every `r` value.

Comment: I unable to see "picked_number_01" id in HTML Part

Comment: Will look at using Arrays, would like this to work first then will look at the DRY principle. I think I need to understand this at a basic level first.

Comment: Where is `picked_number_01`? Does anybody can see that?

Comment: @Exception - hah hah exception handling. nice name.

Comment: I hvae not put up all the html, I will put it all up. There is picked_number_01 value.

Comment: @UllerUller It will be very helpful for us to debug the code if you can put your code in `jsfiddle.net`. With JavaScript whether you are trying to access the element before dynamically creating element or accessing after that does really matters..

Comment: Ok will do now. Thank you

Comment: Have put it up now http://jsfiddle.net/Ulleruller/2q2ne/1/

Comment: As you can see, although not set out with the dry principle, it dose work when you press the "draw week" button.

Answer (score 0):

First, your null exception is probably coming from an html element that is empty or doesn't exist.

Second, use loops to handle all your matching statements.

for example:

```
for (var i = 1; i = <6; i++)
{
    var variable = parseInt(document.getElementById("picked_number_" + i).value);
    if (variable == Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1))
    {
        alert("You've won!");
    }
}
```

In this case you only must have some correct html elements with the id "picked_number_" and the variable number used in the loop. (var i) Your random is generated in the if statement and if that is matching you've won :D

Btw, this script is using an random number between 1 and 100.

Hope this helps you a little.

Comment: Thanks Corstian. Its a little bit more complicated than that. Plaese have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/Ulleruller/2q2ne/7/ to see it working. I just cannot loop it!!!